# How can I downgrade from Windows 7 to Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, battery-life

My system came with Windows Vista business install on D partition. My friends told me about windows 7 and I decided to check it out. Since I installed it on my laptop, the caliberation of my battery dropped and the battery life also dropped from about 2.5hrs to about 45mins.

I thought this was because of the graphics on Windows 7. Now I want to change back to windows vista.

NB: I installed windows 7 directly into C drive without touching D drive at all. How can I reinstall my Vista from D drive?

Comment: -1 for lame title

Comment: Why don't you fix whatever problem that is causing Windows 7 to drain your battery...

Answer (score 1):

Well as long as you have vista actually installed on your D: drive I see no problem with you *booting* onto that drive. If they are physically separate drives it should be as easy as setting some options in your bios. However if it is just a partition on the drive (not a physical piece of hardware) You may have to find some windows recovery disk on-line and look for ways to make sure that it boots onto the the right partition.

Now, as far as switching back goes... I think that windows 7 itself is a much better os that vista, and Windows 7 actually is *less* of a strain on your computer than vista would be. I recommend that you re-calibrate you battery (drain it dead, and then re-charge it). And maybe set your visuals to "basic" (without all of the effects and transparency). If that doesn't work. I think it may be your battery's fault. It seems unreasonable that a change in OS could cause such a drastic change in battery life...

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is fairly common "bug" with Windows 7.  There's information about it left and right if you do a Google search.  You will want to let Windows 7 update itself fully and this should fix the problem (along with doing the battery recalibration that Josh suggested).  Also look into BIOS updates from your manufacturer because Windows 7 doesn't always interact correctly with the hardware with out the update (if its available).  **I would suggest doing that with the laptop plugged in**!

Finally if you can get Windows 7 to work its your much better operating system.  It actually manages the memory of the system significantly better and I don't see that the graphics are enough different between Vista and 7 that it would cause any problem at all.

Comment: Some of the graphics options are much more power hungry, but you can just turn them off.